# What are the prerequisites for using SQL and LINQ with my winforms application in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Specifically if I have a server that I want to use my SQL Server database with do I have to install an SQL database on each server computer? Can I bundle it with the software installation? If I want to utilize LINQ, am I limited to using SQL Server?

On the same note, my database data must be secure. Is there a way I can insure only my program will be able to modify/query my programs database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question 1) do I have to install an SQL database on each server
>   computer?

No, you can have just one sql server hosted and available via the internet

> Question 2) Can I bundle it with the software installation?

Yes you can easiest packager & isntaller I have come across is called Inno Setup

> Quesiton 3) If I want to utilize LINQ, am I limited to using MSSQL?

No because [Language Integrated Query (LINQ, pronounced "link")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) is a Microsoft .NET Framework component that adds native data querying capabilities to .NET languages, although ports exist for Java[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), PHP and JavaScript.

> Quesiton 4) Is there a way I can insure only my program will be able
>   to modify/query my programs database?

Yes your application can use a [connectionstring](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) that will be read from a config file